# How to place a second row of the table at the bottom of the pop up dialog?

Tags: html, html-table, jquery-ui-dialog

It may be a silly question and probably I'm aware of solution but seems that I'm stock for now. :(

I'm displaying a pop up `jQuery dialog` that has a table with 2 rows. 1st row contains `drop down list` and 2nd row has a button:

```
<div id="dvSynch" style="display:none;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSynchUser" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class = "ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" id="btnStartSynch" style="color:#fff;" href="#">START SYNCH</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>              
</div>
```

When displaying the pop up, button is placed directly under `drop down list`.

How can I place it at the button of the `dialog`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it:
I just need to put `style="height:152px; vertical-align:bottom;` into the second `<td>` tag:

```
<div id="dvSynch" style="display:none;">
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSynchUser" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:DropDownList></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:152px; vertical-align:bottom;><a class = "ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" id="btnStartSynch" style="color:#fff;" href="#">START SYNCH</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>              
</div>
```